# Win Form disappears after it is loades with .show()

Tags: c#, winforms, grid, devexpress

I have a grid that I want to pop up in a new window.  The code I am using is below.  The table is populated with the right data all the way through.  The only problem is, when the new winform pops up, it immediately disappears.  Also, it's not displaying the data in the grid.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas?

```
private void gridView1_ShowGridMenu(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        GridHitInfo hitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Point);
        if (hitInfo.InRow)
        {
            var rowData = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(hitInfo.RowHandle, "SP");
            string[] rowDataSplit = rowData.ToString().Split(':');
            using (frmInterfaceLogSelection form = new frmInterfaceLogSelection(Services))
            {
                var sql = rowDataSplit[1].ToString();

                var ds = Services.RunSql(sql);
                var table = ds.FirstTable();

                if (table == null)
                {
                    var error = Services.LastSqlResultError;
                    if (error.Length > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(error);
                    }
                    return;
                }

                table.AcceptChanges();

                this.gridControl1.DataSource = table;
                this.gridView1.Columns.BestFitAll();

                form.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never move the focus from the starting form to the form that `gridview1` is located on.  I will warn you even using `ShowDialog` will likely cause you some threading problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you are disposing of the form.

The `using` statement disposes the form after `form.Show()`, so it disappears.

You likely need to dispose your SQL connection/service connection, rather than your form.

Comment: +1 but the form would be disposed by the GC anyway because it is local, so the using pattern is actually correct. The OP probably needs ShowDialog instead as mentioned by @sa_ddam213 below (for now)

Comment: In that case you'll need to keep references to your forms as member variables and dispose of them in a dispose method later.

Comment: im not  using 'using' and my form still disappears

Answer (score 3):

Try using show dialog

```
  form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: This worked, but my circumstances require me to be able to have multiple windows open and ShowDialog doesn't allow me to click off of the new screen.  Thank you though.

Comment: @SeanSmyth what does you meant? I have the both main and the shown windows opened and working; I just executed the «ShowDialog()» like `(new Thread(() => logForm.ShowDialog())).Start()` to launch it in a separate thread.